# Displaying a message to user

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

**Code with bootstrap:**

```js
function ValidateForm() {
  var fname = document.forms["form1"]["fname"].value;
  var requiredValue = "this value is required";

  if (fname == "") {
    document.getElementById("validation").innerHTML = requiredValue;;
    return false;
  }

}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return ValidateForm()" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <p id="validation"></p>
          <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Enter First Name" data-type="alphanum" />

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Code Without Bootstrap:**

```js
function ValidateForm() {
  var fname = document.forms["form1"]["fname"].value;
  var requiredValue = "this value is required";

  if (fname == "") {
    document.getElementById("validation").innerHTML = requiredValue;
    return false;
  }

}
```

```html
<form id="form1" action="" onsubmit="return ValidateForm()" method="post">
  <p id="validation"></p>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Enter First Name" />
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

why `ValidateForm()` does not work in without a bootstrap code? I am simply accessing the `validation` id but it does not work.But strangely it works in with bootstrap code. i am simply making a script for a user in which `this value is required` should be displayed. Now it does not make sense to me why it is not working with bootstrap?

**NOTE**: In my environment all these code work.

Comment: Use HTML5 required attribute, [https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)

Comment: As far as I can see, in the first snippet `document.forms["form1"]` is undefined, since the `<form>` is missing the attribute: `name="form1"`. I.e. it has absolutely zero to do with bootstrap.

Comment: no i don't need this one.

Comment: @ChrisG yeah you are right tnx man.

Comment: Here's how I'd write this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/6tadobvL/

Comment: i put `onsubmit` in  `<form>`  you made it in script. why?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your code, these are in separate files. The first form have the following code:

```
<form action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return ValidateForm()" method="post">
```

The second one has this:

```
<form id="form1" action="" onsubmit="return ValidateForm()" method="post">
```

Obviously "action_page.php" is not being loaded anymore. Are you loading the script from a different file? Where is this file located and how do you load the actual script on your page?

The following code works as intended, when put in to a single file saved as HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>

    <script>
function ValidateForm(){
   var fname = document.forms["form1"]["fname"].value;
   var requiredValue = "this value is required";

     if(fname == ""){
        document.getElementById("validation").innerHTML= requiredValue;
                 return false;
     }

    }
</script>

<form id="form1" action="" onsubmit="return ValidateForm()" method="post">
<p id="validation"></p>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Enter First Name"/>
<button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: bro thnx for your effort but i did not declare id="form1" in with bootstrap code.